# Структура хранения данных в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево

недавно прочитал статью про [очень подробное устройство баз данных](https://habr.com/company/mailru/blog/266811/). И вот  в связи с этим появились некоторые вопросы...

Там было написано, что в современных базах данных зачастую применяются В+ деревья для хранения данных по индексу, а вот как быть если допустим индексов несколько? И насколько я понял, индекс указывает на некоторую таблицу, которая хранит номера строк соответствующих этому индексу, это получается придется отдельно хранить саму таблицу, а дерево лишь используется только для поиска?

Не мог ли бы кто-нибудь освятить эти вопросы. Да и в целом, если бы кто-нибудь рассказал про возможные способы храния данных в базе данных или дал бы ссылки на полезные ресурсы, то я был бы очень признателен.

Comment: Обычно используются два похода: 1. отдельная область данных и в листьях индексов лежит некий указатель, позволяющий точно встать на запись в области данных. 2. Данные лежат прямо в листьях индекса построенного по первичному ключу. Такой индекс называется _кластаризованным_. Во всех остальных индексах в этом случае в листьях лежит первичный ключ. При поиске по вторичному индексу находится этот ключ, потом на основе него идет поиск в дереве индекса первичного ключа